# linear congruence, find the tens digit of a number

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Hi :) I need to find the tens digit of $27^{2021}$

using linear congruence. so here is my try so far:

$$27^{\varphi(100)} \equiv1\pmod{100} \\~\\
\Longrightarrow27^{40}\equiv1\pmod{100}\Longrightarrow27^{2000}\equiv1\pmod{100} \\~\\ \Longrightarrow27^{2021}\equiv27^{21}\pmod{100}\Longrightarrow27^{2021}\equiv3^{63}\pmod{100}\equiv3^{23}\pmod{100} \\~\\
$$

but I don't know what to do next, because $3^{23}$ is still a big number.

thanks for any help :)
sorry if I have English mistakes...

Comment: [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) would help:  $a^{20}\equiv1\bmod100$ if $\gcd(a,100)=1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner wow really helps thank!!!

Comment: The Carmichael function is also known as the reduced totient function

Comment: @J.W.Tanner can you think on another way?, because I didn't learn it yet

Comment: Did you learn that $a^{20}\equiv1\bmod25$ and $a^{2}\equiv1\bmod4$ so $a^{20}\equiv1\bmod4$ if $\gcd(a,25)=\gcd(a,4)=1$?  Alternatively, you could show $3^{20}=9^{10}=(10-1)^{10}\equiv1\bmod100$ using the binomial theorem

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, I think I got it :) thanks!!!

Comment: You can use the *fast exponentiation algorithm*. It only requires $5$ squarings and $3$ multiplications (each modular).